# Analyzing temporally correlated data using 'date' as a fixed effect; do you convert to a factor first or leave as a 'Date' class in R?

Tags: r, date, time, time-series, anova

The short and sweet of the question is this: How do you deal with time as a parameter in an repeat ANOVA in R?

I have repeat observations of the number of plants growing in pots taken at 3 day, 7 day, and 14 day intervals coming from greenhouse data. Incorporating the time element is important as each species grows at a different rate with some germinating very quickly while others take monthes. Variation in survey frequency reflects those changes. I am looking at the effect of a treatment (2 levels), species (10 levels), and date (n=4). I control for variation by pot using it as a random effect. This is all summed up by the following equation:

```
Establishment ~ Date + Species + Treatment + (1|Pot)
```

I've built a quick simulation of my data and ran it through lmer. My confusion stems from how I handle the date variable. Do I leave the date variable in the 'Date' class or should it be factored? Perhaps I have misunderstood the literature but it seems that both can be used but I am hoping to go with what is most appropriate.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(lme4)

gmean <- c(.4,.5,.6,.65) #Simulate 4 means to represent date and treatment effects
sigma_g <- .1            #Standard deviation
reps <- 30               #Replicates
nspp <- 10               #Simulated number of species
ntrt <- 2                #Simulated number of treatments
n <- nspp*reps           #Total reps for simulation

tibble(est = rnorm(n, gmean, sigma_g),
       date = rep(seq(ymd('2018-04-07'),ymd('2018-05-03'), by = '1 week'), length.out=n),
       species = rep(1:nspp, each=n/nspp),
       trt  = rep(c("control","trt"), length.out=n),
       pot_id = paste0(species,"-",trt)) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(factor(.)),species:trt) %>% 
  glimpse() -> sim_df 

mm <- lmer(est ~ date + species + trt  + (1|pot_id), data=sim_df, REML=F)
mm.factored <- lmer(est ~ factor(date) + species + trt  + (1|pot_id), data=sim_df, REML=F)

anova(mm,mm.factored)

Data: sim_df
Models:
mm: est ~ date + species + trt + (1 | pot_id)
mm.factored: est ~ factor(date) + species + trt + (1 | pot_id)
            Df     AIC     BIC logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
mm          14 -515.80 -463.94 271.90  -543.80                           
mm.factored 15 -518.39 -462.83 274.19  -548.39 4.5909      1    0.03214 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My 'real' dataset has closer to 6000 objects.

Comment: It would surely depend on what you want to do. However, I can't really see much point in keeping a variable of class date in mixed-effects modeling.

Comment: @Suren - I was/am still unsure if its the difference between assessing date as a continuous vs discrete variable. In my real dataset, the sampling is not perfectly regular, sometimes surveys occur twice in a week and other times they occur bimonthly. It seems that factoring the data would not account for changes in the survey frequency changing.

Comment: I suggest https://stats.stackexchange.com for this question. Also, include what you have written about sampling irregularity to the question. I have flagged the question to migrate to stats.exchange.

Comment: When you leave it as Date, it's treated as a continuous variable, so you expect est to change per unit time. It depends on the data, if you see that the change of est wrt Date is not necessarily linear, then use it as a factor.

Comment: @Suren - Thanks for the suggestion on migrating, I was torn between the two sites.

Comment: Well, I had also suggested the migration, but it got declined. So it sounds like you picked the right site after all